# I am not able to use jAlert in my code ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to use jAlert dialog box and I am trying to replace all the alert box using jAlert but the browser is throwing this error.

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: jAlert is not defined ReferenceError: jAlert is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/Kn1/insertion_checking.js:69:13)
at j (http://localhost:8080/Kn1/jquery-3.0.0.min.js:2:29588)
at k (http://localhost:8080/Kn1/jquery-3.0.0.min.js:2:29902) undefined
```

Please Help me to use jAlert. Thank You!! Here is the code

```
//Inserting jquery here
var jq = document.createElement("script");

jq.addEventListener("load", mySubmitFunction); // pass my hoisted function
jq.src = "jquery-3.0.0.min.js";
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(jq);

var instance1 = 0 ;
var instance2 = 0 ;
var x = 0 ;

//work_over_history: To check for each new element added
function add1_check(){
instance1++ ;
console.log("checking: " +instance1) ;
}

//crane_job_history: To check for each new element added
function add2_check(){
instance2++ ;
console.log("checking: " +instance2) ;
}


// Function for checking the from and to date 
function mySubmitFunction(){
    console.log("DATE:") ;
    console.log("instance zero area") ;

    var from_work_date = document.getElementById("from_work").value ;
    var to_work_date = document.getElementById("to_work").value ;
    console.log(from_work_date)  ;
    console.log(to_work_date) ;
    console.log(typeof(to_work_date));

    var fw_date = new Date(from_work_date) ;
    console.log(typeof(fw_date)) ;
    var to_date = new Date(to_work_date);
    console.log(typeof(to_date)) ;

    if( fw_date >= to_date ){

        console.log("Error") ;
        alert(" Check Your Working History : \"From Date\" entered is Larger than \"To Date\"") ;
        return false ;
    }
    if( instance1 > 0 ){

    while(x !== instance1 ){

    alert("diagram") ;
    x++ ;
    var from_work_date = document.getElementById("from_work" +x).value ;
    var to_work_date = document.getElementById("to_work" +x).value ;
    console.log("From:" +from_work_date)  ;
    console.log("To" +to_work_date) ;
    console.log(typeof(to_work_date));

    var fw_date = new Date(from_work_date) ;
    console.log(typeof(fw_date)) ;
    var to_date = new Date(to_work_date);
    console.log(typeof(to_date)) ;

    if( fw_date >= to_date ){

        console.log("Error") ;
        console.log("Game") ;
        $(document).ready( function() {
        jAlert("Please Check Your Work Hitory","Alert Dialog") ;
    });
    return false ;
    } //End of if statement     
   } // End of while statement x != instance1
 }// End of if statement of instance1
```

} // mySubmitFunction()

Comment: Where do you load the jAlert library?

Comment: I did not know that we must add jAlert Library. Thank you!! But how should load it?

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://github.com/VersatilityWerks/jAlert#setup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must load your library in your HTML page :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jalert.js"></script>
```

(if jalert.js is in the same directory that your HTML page)

Comment: Hi I want to add jAlert in my javascript file how should I do that because I need to call the jAlert when a particular exception occurred and after that even the CSS for the file.

Comment: You have to put the jAlert code at the beginning of your JS file and you will be able to call jAlert whenever you want.

Comment: Where should I add CSS file in the javascript file?

Comment: You can't load a CSS file from a JS file, you must include the CSS into your HTML page, like this :

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet_file.css" />`